# Rails 4 edit form unable to find path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm doing a simple CRUD, and I have an issue with `edit/update`. This is how my form looks like :

```
= simple_form_for @receipt do |f|
  = render 'shared/error_messages', object: @receipt
  = f.input :purchase_date, as: :string, input_html: {'data-provide' => 'datepicker'}
  = f.input :amount, as: :string, input_html: {'data-provide' => 'datepicker'}
  = f.association :store
```

So for new action I have this in the view :

```
h2 Create new receipt
  = render 'form'
```

I initialize my `@receipt` instance variable in the new controller action. However when I try to do edit, this is the content of edit view :

```
h2 Edit receipt
  = render 'form'
```

I get this error :

```
undefined method `receipt_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f943b6f3750>:0x007f943d5ce5d0>
```

On the first line of the `form` partial. This is how my routes look like :

```
resource :receipts do
    collection do
      get :index
    end
end
```

Weird thing about routes is that in the case I didn't add the `get :index`, routes for index wouldn't get generated, this is the output of my `rake routes` with index present in the collection under resource :

```
receipts GET    /receipts(.:format)      receipts#index
              POST   /receipts(.:format)      receipts#create
 new_receipts GET    /receipts/new(.:format)  receipts#new
edit_receipts GET    /receipts/edit(.:format) receipts#edit
              GET    /receipts(.:format)      receipts#show
              PATCH  /receipts(.:format)      receipts#update
              PUT    /receipts(.:format)      receipts#update
              DELETE /receipts(.:format)      receipts#destroy
```

I mean I could pass the url to both edit and new form which would make it work I guess. It used to be redundant.

My question is what am I doing wrong here, this is my first project with rails 4, is this a rails 4 thing?

**Update**
Per comment, instead of using the instance variable from the controller, I passed the new local variable into the partial like this :

```
= render 'form', object: @receipt
```

And changed form partial to:

```
= simple_form_for object do |f|
```

Still get the same result as with instance variable.

Comment: I didn't think you could pass instance variables directly from your controller through to your partial.  Have you tried passing what you need in as a local?

Comment: replace `resource` to `resources` and remove `get :index`. It may fix your issue

Comment: @Zakwan please make this an answer, solved my issue, wow nice find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `resource` with `resources` and remove `get :index`. It may fix your issue

Answer (score -1):

please replace  `resource :receipts` with `resources :receipts`
I hope this will resolve your problem.

also you dont need to add `get "index"` action because `resources` keyword it self provides `CRUD` actions like (index, new, edit, etc.)